# Apache2 shows 404 error for sub links or path in laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, http-status-code-404

I have using apache2 for Laravel on Ubuntu 18.04. While I am using the domain name it shows the index.php page. But when I clicking the sub links or path, it shows 404 error.

I am using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#web-server-configuration) tutorial for htaccess

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-company-website/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/ example.com-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-company-website/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/my-company-website/.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding given Directory tags inside your VirtualHost *:80 as well as inside port VirtualHost *:433 tags as shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ..................

    <Directory /var/www/my-company-website/public>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

          .................
</VirtualHost>
```